# Find the relative path of a file in a project

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have my project files set in this format:

```
/home/user/proj/source
/home/user/proj/source/src1
/home/user/proj/source/src1
/home/user/proj/header ...etc
```

I have a way to find the project path when viewing any source file

```
"/home/user/proj"
```

Also, (buffer-file-name) gives the full absolute path of a given source file.

How to write a lisp function that extract the relative path of a source file?

Meaning, if I am viewing

```
/home/user/proj/source/src1/file.c
```

I would like to have the path

```
"source/src1/file.c"
```

The following function gives me the project path:

```
(defun upward-find-file (filename &optional startdir)
  (let ((dirname (expand-file-name
          (if startdir startdir ".")))
    (found nil) ; found is set as a flag to leave loop if we find it
    (top nil))  ; top is set when we get
            ; to / so that we only check it once
    ; While we've neither been at the top last time nor have we found
    ; the file.
    (while (not (or found top))
      ; If we're at / set top flag.
      (if (string= (expand-file-name dirname) "/")
      (setq top t))
      ; Check for the file
      (if (file-exists-p (expand-file-name filename dirname))
      (setq found t)
    ; If not, move up a directory
    (setq dirname (expand-file-name ".." dirname))))
    ; return statement
    (if found (concat dirname "/") nil)))
```

I always have "Makefile" in the main project folder, so

```
(setq dirname (upward-find-file "Makefile" startdir))
```

Takes care of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `locate-dominating-file` and `file-relative-name`.

```
(let ((fname (buffer-file-name)))
  (file-relative-name fname (locate-dominating-file fname "Makefile")))
```

N.B. `locate-dominiating-file` returns `nil` if it can't find anything.

Comment: Yes. This is it. Brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```lisp
(defun file-name-make-relative (filename reference)
  (interactive)
  (let ((reduced-path-reference)
        (common-pos 0)
        (depth 0)
        (pos 0)
        (retval ""))
    (while (eq (aref filename common-pos) (aref reference common-pos))
      (setq common-pos (+ common-pos 1)))
    (setq reduced-path-reference (substring reference (+ common-pos 1)))
    (while (< pos (length (substring reference (+ common-pos 1))))
      (if (eq (aref reduced-path-reference pos) (aref "/" 0))
          (setq depth (+ depth 1)))
      (setq pos (+ pos 1)))
    (dotimes (i depth)
      (setq retval (concat retval "../")))
    (setq retval (concat retval (substring filename common-pos)))
    retval))
```

It has not been tested very thoroughly, however, in my simple testcases it worked as expected. Given a file `filename` and a reference directory `reference` (must have trailing slash, I can't remember which function does this automatically, can someone comment?) this function will calculate the relative path from `reference` to `filename`.

**Example:**

```lisp
(file-name-make-relative "/usr/local/bin/exec" "/usr/local/root/bin/")
```

Result:

```
"../../bin/exec"
```

Comment: Thanks elemakil.
I believe you meant (file-name-make-relative "/usr/local/root/bin/exec" "/usr/local/root/bin/")
Because thats what I am looking for basically.
Something like: (file-name-make-relative (buffer-file-name) "/home/proj")
And the output should be:
"source/src1/file.c"
Your code "when adding the /root/" part gives error upon starting

Answer (score 1):

Install [`f.el`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el), a comprehensive file and directory manipulation library. Then run function [`f-relative`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-relative-path-optional-dir):

```
(f-relative "some/path/is/long" "some/path/was/short") ; => "../../is/long"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak this code to your needs:

```
(defun java-package-name (file)
  "Generates package name for FILE, based on path."
  (let* ((f (file-name-directory file))
         (rem
          (car
           (sort
            (delq nil
                  (mapcar
                   (lambda(x)
                     (and (string-match (expand-file-name x) f) 
                          (substring f (match-end 0))))
                   (parse-colon-path (getenv "CLASSPATH"))))
            (lambda (a b) (< (length a) (length b)))))))
    (cond
     ((null rem)
      "Not on CLASSPATH.")
     ((= 0 (length rem))
      "At root of CLASSPATH")
     (t
      (mapconcat
       #'downcase
       (delete "" (split-string rem "[\\\\/]"))
       ".")))))
```

Comment: Thanks abo-abo.
Could you give me an example of what the output of your function is given a filename?
I am not sure I understand how it works.

Comment: CLASSPATH has is a colon-separated list of root directories.
The file in question is on CLASSPATH, in one or more of the sub-directories of the
root directory. I search for the closest one, i.e. the one for which the
relative path is shortest. Then the path is concatenated with dots
to form a Java package path, but you can drop that part.
So the function returns `typeinfo.factory` for a file `~/foo/bar/typeinfo/factory/Factory.java`
if `~/foo/bar/` is on CLASSPATH.